# What is the assembly reference of ImageExtension

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

Controller:

```
private string ReadFileInBase64(ImageExtension extension, string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                fileName,
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.Read))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(streamReader);
                    byte[] fileContents = streamReader.ToArray();

                    string base64MimeFileContents = ConvertToBase64(extension, fileContents);

                    //(string MimeType, string ParsedBase64Contents) = GetBase64MimeType (base64MimeFileContents);

                    return base64MimeFileContents;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here ImageExtension  have no assemply reference or using directive.
I want to know that what is assembly reference of ImageExtension .

Comment: Typically that means you forget to add a reference to some package or need add a `using The.Package.Namespace`

Comment: I know that but what will be package.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody knows that unless you tell us more information. For example, did you copy the code somewhere?